# XCode and SCM conflicts

Tags: xcode, macos, version-control, svn

Is there a decent Subversion client available for XCode? I am so tempted to write my own as of this morning after having a conflict on an update. I've done merges manually editing the ">>> mine" and "<<< theirs" markers but there has GOT to be a better way in this day and age. Does anyone know of an easy way to resolve conflicts graphically? It seems like SCM conflicts and svn history queries are my two most missed features in all of the Mac SVN clients I've seen so far. I use Versions and sometimes the built in XCode SCM support. I've also looked briefly at Cornerstones web site. (Is Cornerstone any better?) Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As a GUI, [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) offers a basic conflict editor (though I find the the application very slow to refresh on a large source tree).  Often I find myself going back to Emacs which has support for subversion via [Psvn.el](http://www.xsteve.at/prg/vc_svn/), and that has a very capable 3 way diff with ancestor revisions, custom region skipping and other goodies.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [git-svn](http://utsl.gen.nz/talks/git-svn/intro.html) with [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) for most things.  The GitX commit interface is *so nice* it's really hard to go back to anything else.

For conflicts I use Emacs, which offers really nice, fully editable, color-coded 3-way merge.

You also might check out the WWDC 2010 videos/slides (free at Apple's site if you're a registered developer) regarding SCM support in the upcoming version of Xcode.